# Loop through a two-dimensional array with actions on change of a value in a column

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, design-patterns, conditional-statements

A very common problem while looping throug a two-dimensional array (representing a table) is to have an action to execute only when a value in a column changes. To give a concrete example:

**Output some HTML from tabular data.**
Given this table

```
category | product
------------------
Vehicles | Bike
Vehicles | Car
Clothes  | Shirt
```

Create HTML like this:

```
<h1>Vehicles</h1>Bike<br />Car<hr />
<h1>Clothes</h1>Shirt<hr />
```

To solve the problem, I could change the code like this:

```
$current_category = '';
$first = true;
foreach($table as $row){
    if ($row['category'] != $current_category){
        if(!$first){
            // after a group
            $echo '<hr />'; 
        }
        // before a group
        echo '<h1>'.$row['category'].'</h1>';
    } else if (!$first){
        // inside a group
        echo '<br />'; 
    }
    // foreach line
    echo $row['category'];
    $current_category = $row['category'];
    $first = false;
}
// after a group, duplicated code
$echo '<hr />';
```

I feel that this is more complicated than necessary. Also there is code duplication for what I want to execute after the group.

The code for this relatively simple requirement is already convoluted. It get's almost impossible, if we need to watch two changing columns in the array.

I'm looking for an approach of this problem that keeps the code easy to read, while being able to loop through the array and execute some code

- foreach line
- before a group of lines
- after a group of lines
- inside a group of lines

I hope the question is clear, even though I have some difficulty to explain this general problem in simple terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store your products in array of categories

```
$categories = [];
foreach ($table as $row) {
  $categories[$row['category']][] = $row['product'];
}
```

And then output them directly with an implode to get a new line between each values

```
foreach ($categories as $category => $products) {
  echo '<h1>' . $category . '</h1>';
  echo implode ('<br>', $products);
}
```

For the general problem this will give something like :

```
$categories = [];
foreach($table as $row) $categories[$row['category']][] = $row;
foreach($categories as $category => $rows){
    // before a group
    echo '<h1>'.$row['category'].'</h1>';
    $first = true;
    foreach($rows as $row){
        if(!$first){
            // inside a group
            echo '<br />';
        }
        // foreach line
        echo $row['category'];
        $first = false;
    }
    // after a group
    $echo '<hr />';
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for the specific problem. When my `echo`s would be any arbitrary code, the `implode` would obviously not work.

Comment: Do you think rebuilding the array is still the way to go?

Comment: Rebuilding the array makes the whole process way easier than before. Really. It's not that bad to re-do things when it increases the logic of your code sometimes.

Comment: I would definitely rebuild the array this way.  If you want to apply arbitrary code to your products, then instead of `implode()`, you would `foreach($products as $product) { //arbitrary code }`.